# dedicated server on ubuntu 20 with plesk obsidian 18.xx

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, plesk, dedicated

Hi guys hope you can help me.
I have a powerful dedicated server running on ubuntu 20 with plesk obsidian 18.
Yesterday everthing was fine i have running 5 Domains on it and all was working.
Today in the morning all of these pages/domains were running on this dedicated server are whitepaged when i open them. Aswell the plesk control.

So started searching the error first of all i restarded the server severy times. then i saw it must be a database issue because i cant start sql commands and can not login to sql databases.

root/ftp works well. https://gyazo.com/d7f1a675e0c835d10e129d43ace860aa

how can i resolve this problem? for me it looks like the database server has deleted by himself but im not that good in these hosting things. If this problem is not to resolve maybe you can tell me how i can backup all databases stored on my server.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Install the backup, that looks more like a hack or a reset and talk to the support

Comment: https://gyazo.com/63b3a8ed886aa740182a9ed14d6ff06d

Comment: `yu must have a backup or the hoster has one, hopefully

Comment: maybe i have to enlarge the disk space for my ubuntu partiotion?

Comment: ok i have found where all backups are stored, i'll just reinstall plesk

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.